# Azure Dataflow Unable To Extract Data From String

Tags: azure-data-factory

In my dataflow I have a string which is actually a JSON representation of the object I'm trying to unmarshall into arrays. The string has this structure:

```
  "vehicles": [
    {
      "id": "uk-777",
      "discontinued": "2025-12-25",
      "released": "2012-12-25",
      "ranged": true,
      "discontinued_label": "month"
    },
    {
      "id": "uk-778",
      "discontinued": "2025-12-25",
      "released": "2012-12-25",
      "ranged": false,
      "discontinued_label": "year"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've needed to use several prior steps in the dataflow just to get the data consistently into this shape as a string. Now I need to flatten out the 'vehicles' array so as to get columns with the id, discontinued, released, ranged and discontinued_label values.

I thought it would be simple to use the cast activity to recast the string as a complex - but I'm having problems getting that to work. I think I need to provide a type mapping for the complex type but I can't get it working (not sure of the syntax) and there is also a message on the Azure documentation for the 'cast' activity suggesting that complex typecasting is 'not currently available'.

I'd imagine that getting from my structured 'string' to the columns I need should be straightforward, but I seem to be hitting a brick wall. Any suggestions would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your JSON is in string format, **Cast transformation** won't give the required result.

You can use **Parse transformation and Flatten transformation** to achieve your requirement.

This is my source JSON which is in string format.

[image]

Now, use parse transformation and give the configurations like below.

[image]

Give the below expression in the **Output column type** and click on **save**.

```
(id as string,
discontinued as date,
released as date,
ranged as boolean,
discontinued_label as string)[]
```

[image]

You can change the data type as per your requirement.

You will get the output array like below.

[image]

Now, use flatten transformation on this. Use the Rule based mapping to get all individual columns from the array.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: The dataset I am working with is considerably more complex than the 'vehicles' one I used in the questiom, for simplicity. Because your answer was so clear and instructional, I was able to parse all the elements out of my real-world use case exactly as I'd hoped. I cannot thank you enough! I'm very grateful!